# jQuery scrollTop() for navigation

Tags: jquery, scrolltop, nav

I'm trying to make a navigation for my website and would greatly appreciate any assistance. I'd like to use a smooth scroll to the desired div.My website will be one page, so I need the nav link to take them to corresponding div.
thx

Here is my html for my nav:

```
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="span8" >
<ul class="nav">
    <li class="active" id="aboutlink"><a href="#">about</a></li>
    <li class="active" id="worklink"><a href="#">work</a></li>          
    </ul><!--end .nav-->
</div><!--end .span8-->

<div id="about">
<p>blah, blah...</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    $("#click").click(function (){
        $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: $("#div2").offset().top
                 }, 2000);
        return false;
    });
});
```

Sample:

http://jsfiddle.net/7dzK7/1/

Comment: Thanks Chris! Your solution worked great! I was making it so much harder than it needed to be.